# AppBar is scrollable somehow

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

Using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
```

in build.gradle (Module: app)'s dependencies block, I'm trying to make use of the new Design Support Library.

The app consists of a Main Activity, Toolbar with TabLayout, ViewPager with Fragment that contains RecyclerView.

Layouts below before the description of the issue.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

**item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.widget.TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

    <android.widget.TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**The problem**

When the app is started, scrolling on the AppBarLayout area (Toolbar + TabLayout) does not do anything, but after having scrolled the RecyclerView/sideways on ViewPager, the Toolbar and TabLayout become scrollable too! Meaning they act the same as scrolling the RecyclerView, thus hiding the Toolbar.

**Tried**

Since I'm not experienced, I worked off of CheeseSquare, and checked it does not act like my app does, so I have no idea how to solve this at this point. Tried messing with layouts but can't figure out.

**Question**
How can the AppBarLayout area be not scrollable as supposed to be on app start, but change after scrolling RecyclerView/sideways on ViewPager?

Comment: Everything seems fine to me, however you might consider going back to 22.2.1 just for the sake of clarification , 23 has more bug than 22 has, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Could be... just realized the cheesecake was from apk not self compiled so it does use <23. Still a mystery how can it change to scrollable. Will try suggestion.